# Infopath-Populate ID from SharePoint List

Tags: infopath, column, id

I have an InfoPath 2013 form with multiple views with a lot of fields for users to fill out.  My final page after the user submits the form through the main data connection is a view that says "Thank you.  Your request has been submitted."  What I'm trying to do here is display the ID number from the SharePoint list as a reference for the user.  I believe the ID gets created in SP once an item is created, but I can't get the ID to display on my InfoPath form.  It keeps showing blank.  Can somebody please help me?

Thank you so much.

Chris

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a secondary data connection to get the list data, then from data connection selection list from the right side panel, select the secondary data connection and drag and drop the **ID** field to form.

For reference, you can refer to the below article :

[How to auto populate field in InfoPath based on another field](https://global-sharepoint.com/sharepoint-2/how-to-auto-populate-field-in-infopath-based-on-another-field/)

Comment: Thank you so much.  Your directions and link solved my problem.  Take care!

Comment: My pleasure and I am glad that it helped you :-)